# Retrieve a jQuery element from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am storing jQuery elements in an array, and I need to retrieve them.

I am now doing it like

```
var arr = [];

arr.push( $(someElement) );
```

Then I try to retrieve it by doing:

```
arr.indexOf($(someElement));
```

But it doesn't work as all jQuery elements look the same `e.fn.e.init[1]`

I'd rather not name (key) each of them because I have a lot of elements and if I could reference them similarly to how I'm trying to, it would be better for me.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you storing your jQuery objects in an array ? You can't save jQuery objects to preserve their states as JQuery objects are simply wrappers to the DOM elements chosen by your selector. If the DOM changes, then those changes will be reflected by the jQuery object. If you want to preserve the old values, you should store the properties you want to keep rather than the entire jQuery object. Alternatively, you could also store your jQuery string inside an array:

```
var arr = [];

arr.push(someElement);
```

When needed you can then query if your element is still contained in the array

```
 if (arr.indexOf(someElement)){
    $(someElement).dostuff......
 }
```

Comment: Hi -- I want to keep a reference to the elements for an error validation system on inputs. If the input doesn't have errors anymore, I'd splice it out. If it still has errors, then it's still in the array and I can still refer to them and make their border colors red, and do whatever other actions on them.

Comment: In that case, can't you just have an array of containing `someElement` entries and then call the the query operator `$` when you need to refer to them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working this way :-)